# how to return 0 for non-existent months in mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
 var start = new Date();
    start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    start.setMonth(start.getMonth() - 12);

    var end = new Date();
    end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);


Orders.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                'created_at': {
                    $gte: start,
                    $lte: end
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "year": { "$year": "$created_at" },
                    "month": { "$month": "$created_at" }
                },
                "total_sales": { "$sum": "$total" }
            },
    
        },
        {
            $sort: { '_id.year': 1, '_id.month': 1, }
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                '_id.month': {
                    $let: {
                        vars: {
                            monthsInString: [, 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                        },
                        in: {
                            $arrayElemAt: ['$$monthsInString', '$_id.month']
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        ])
```

The above query returns:

```
[
   { _id: { year: 2019, month: 'Dec' }, total_sales: 1800 },
   { _id: { year: 2020, month: 'Apr' }, total_sales: 5700 },
   { _id: { year: 2020, month: 'May' }, total_sales: 6630 },
   { _id: { year: 2020, month: 'Jun' }, total_sales: 690 },
   { _id: { year: 2020, month: 'Jul' }, total_sales: 1600 },
   { _id: { year: 2020, month: 'Aug' }, total_sales: 13430 }
 ]
```

How can I change it in a way where it returns 0 for total_sales for that month if no document exists for that month. For example in January there is no orders. I want it to return `total_sales=0` for that month and every other month that has no document. Past 12 months or 6 months.

sample doc:

```
_id : 5f3d0c6677d1471d8a8438e1
orderid :"aydc1kehke1aj47l"
user :5f3cf2c61282c415bfd2a432
products :Array
total : 1800
firstName:"ishak"
lastName: "ertem"
created_at:2020-03-21T11:26:30.647+00:00
```

Comment: Post a sample document structure

Answer (score 2):

Having below structure (after `$sort` stage):

```
[
    { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12 }, total_sales: 1800 },
    { _id: { year: 2020, month: 4 }, total_sales: 5700 },
    { _id: { year: 2020, month: 5 }, total_sales: 6630 },
    { _id: { year: 2020, month: 6 }, total_sales: 690 },
    { _id: { year: 2020, month: 7 }, total_sales: 1600 },
    { _id: { year: 2020, month: 8 }, total_sales: 13430 }
]
```

You can use [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) to generate a list of 12 integers that can be iterated for each year using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and matched with incoming data using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) and [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html). Additionally [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html) can be used to specify a default value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.month",
            months: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            months: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [ 1, 12 ] },
                    as: "monthIndex",
                    in: {
                        $ifNull: [
                            { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$months", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.month", "$$monthIndex" ] } } } , 0 ] },
                            { _id: { year: "$_id", month: "$$monthIndex" }, total_sales: 0 }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$months"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$months" }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1K7E2kA9wci)

Comment: But the OP's months are string not indices

Comment: @KunalMukherjee after the `$sort` stage months are integers since they're being passed  as an array index into `$arrayElemAt` operator in the last one

Comment: Is there any way to map this index back to string months, I have been trying to update your answer [`here`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tKFoiDDObs8) let me know if you can map them back to strings

Comment: @KunalMukherjee just use OP's last `$addFields` stage: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gdCUtD1VUfA